# Custom ArrayAdapter Showing same image for each entry

Tags: java, android

Color is being changed for all items to the LAST item in the list, for instance if the last color is black, then ALL items have black (instead of the correct color)

```
ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv);


    LogAdapter la = new LogAdapter(m_this,R.layout.logspinner,data);
    lv.setAdapter(la);
```

Please see class below - ICON is the imageview that should be unique per item

I am passing in different hex values - when I step through code the hex calue is used correctly

```
public class LogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, ?>> {

public LogAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public LogAdapter(Context context, int resource,  ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.logspinner, null);
    }

   HashMap<String, ?> p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        ImageView imageV = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



        if(imageV != null) {
            Object o = p.get("Icon");
            if (o != null) {
                String colorhex = (String.valueOf(o));
                Drawable myIcon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ffffff);
                myIcon.setColorFilter(colorhex, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

                imageV.setImageDrawable(myIcon);
            }
        }

    }

    return v;
}}
```

Modifications attempted:

```
       if(imageV != null) {
                Object o = p.get("Icon");
                if (o != null) {
                    String colorhex = (String.valueOf(o));

                    Drawable myIcon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ffffff);
                    myIcon.setColorFilter(PColor(colorhex), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

                    Bitmap b = drawableToBitmap(myIcon);

                    imageV.setImageBitmap(b);
                }
            }
  public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: So this is a same icon just with different color filter, and you are sure that colorHex is appropriate for each value?

Comment: Hi yes, same resource - and yes verified colorhex works - I have tried them all and they all work

Comment: Implement ViewHolder tactics your problem will be no more

Comment: @Elltz how would that help? A viewholder according to this http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html simply just makes it so it doesn't have to look up a drawable with find for each time

Answer (score 0):

adding mutate fixes the issue

```
Drawable myIcon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_ffffff);
                    myIcon = myIcon.mutate();
                    myIcon.setColorFilter(PColor(colorhex), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

source:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html

Answer (score -1):

Resources in Context.getResources() are preinstantiated only once for better reuse and less memory pressure. Therefore essentially you're using the same instance of Drawable so only the last color filter applies in this case.

Besides, Drawables should be used to actually draw something to a canvas. You should be able to 1) create a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and a Canvas using [new Canvas(Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)), 2) draw this Drawable to that Canvas, and 3) set that Bitmap to the ImageView.

Comment: Besides, you might want to avoid creating a Bitmap every time getView() is called, but I'll leave that implementation to you.

Comment: Does not appear to be the correct answer - edits to original have been included above - and it does not work - does the exact same thing